# Source filtering when using JAVA API

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Jest Client along with Query builder. Not able to find how to perform source filtering.

How to set _source field to false using query builder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`fetchSource()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/cd88b7724e9d098d9d1a1b83a6c9bb688a0fd9ae/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/builder/SearchSourceBuilder.java#L649-L656) like this:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
    .query(query)
    .fetchSource(false);
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for!